# Is it safe to disable thermal daemon?

Tags: 18.04, services, lts

After install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop in new labtop, I had experience the slow shutodown problem where cups service lagged shutdown process.

As I don't need networkf print service, I disabled cups service with following command

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

Thanks to disabling cups service, shutdown process was accelerated. But thermal daemon still lagged the shutdown process.

Is it safe to disable thermal service?
If so, what is safe way to disable the thermal service?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: What would `thermald` ever want to tell you? "Help I'm Overheating!"? If you want to miss this crucial warning.... NO disabling it is NOT SAFE.

Comment: thermald manages your fan speed.  Disabling it would likely leave it at the min or max speed, neither case is really desired.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.